# Angular DI Singleton

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service `MyService` declared with the following decorator:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

An excerpt from its implementation is:

```
private myData: string = '';

setData(data: string) {
   this.myData = data;
}

getData(): string {
    return this.myData;
}
```

I have a component `MyComponent` and its URL is `http://localhost:4200/sn8j8h`.
On the first load (by navigating to it using routes), I set the service's data:

```
constructor (private srv: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    let s = this.srv.getData();
}

// this event triggers as I have demonstrated it by putting break points in
onSomeEvent() { 
    this.srv.SetData('my data');
}
```

But on the 2nd load (by hitting the Enter key when my focus is in the browser address bar where the URL is `http://localhost:4200/sn8j8h`), on `ngOnInit`, `srv.getData()` returns an empty string instead of the previous data `my data`.

The documentation says DI with `provided in root` is reused across the app. But in my example it doesn't seem to be reused.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's because your Application has reloaded and all the state that was there in the service has now gone. If you navigate to a route via Angular Routing. Angular restores the state of your application. You being in the address bar and pressing the Enter key is just like reloading the Application and the application state.

Comment: I have provided you 2 ways to handle this. If you need more clarification, please explain the use case for maintaining the data after application reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because after reloading the app (by pressing `ENTER` or `F5`), your entire app is reloaded. So, any data which has been previously saved by the service or component is lost.

There can be 2 approaches to solve this:

1. Using `localStorage` which **Debabrata Paul Chowdhury** has already explained. So, I wont get into that. If your intention is not save any data client side , which will have it's own implementation and use cases (data consistency) when you start saving data client side.
2. I would recommend you to create a angular component flow in such a way that the data is automatically set before the component is loaded. And if, the data is empty, the component should handle it properly.

It depends on your business case of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you hit ENTER on browser URL the data stored in the services will lost because application is reloaded. To get the data after hitting enter on browser URL you should store the data in localstorage and cookies as well along with service.

```
private myData: string = '';

    setData(data: string) {
      this.myData = data;
      localStorage.setItem("dataKey",data);    
    }

    getData(): string {
       return this.myData? this.myData :localStorage.getItem("dataKey");
    }
```

To remove item form local storage you can use

```
localStorage.removeItem("dataKey");
```

Comment: Thank you very much